# Perl trying to read pdf file with # in name

Tags: xml, perl

I have a Perl script developed by a programmer who I can't find any more. I have been trying to learn Perl and I think I have narrowed down the issue.

The script downloads products feeds and then it add the data to the database. It then looks up and downloads description etc from a remote server in XML.

Each XML file is named after the product model. Now some models have a `#` symbol in the middle.
The script wasn't downloading any of these XML files.

I got told by the XML provider to substitute `#` with `%23` in the request.

So before the request is made I added:

```
$data->{'manufacturer_model'} =~ s/#/%23/;
```

Now the XML files are being downloaded. The problem I have is the Perl script is not parsing them. It parses all the XML files without `#` but anything with `#` is not being parsed. I think it is treating anything after the hash as a comment.

I have searched and looked everywhere; any pointer to some help would be appreciated.

Comment: No, `#` is fine in substitutions.  For example, the one-liner `perl -e '$_="#abc";s/#/%23/;print "$_\n";'` prints out `%23abc`, as expected.  Please include some code and include all error messages that you're getting.

Comment: Are the files on disk with a `#` in the name, or do they contain `%23` instead?  If the latter, you'll need either to open the file by the name with `%23` in it or to rename them before you open them by the name with the `#`.

Comment: # only starts a comment in the perl code, not the data.  The code above won't cause a problem because the # is quoted by the //.  If you have some other code that contains '#' please post it.

Comment: How exactly these files (#-ridden names) are not being parsed? Is it the XML::Simple mistake, or something else?